# Spring boot actuator health check context path

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, health-monitoring

My Spring boot server context-path : /test

I have authentication setup for the "https://localhost:8443/test" base path using nginx configuration and the rest api's within this base path are edge services.

Problem: I don't want my health service to be exposed as an edge service and undergo authentication. But actuator's health check comes as admin service and the admin's context-path is not overriding the application's base path.

Is there any tweak which I can do in my application to differentiate context path between rest api's and actuator's health check api's.

Dropwizard does this pretty easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use spring-security to secure the management endpoints:

Add `spring-boot-starter-security` to your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This by itself will secure all endpoints. If you want only the mgmt ones secured, add this property:

```
security.basic.enabled=false
```

You can also set a different user/password for that:

```
security.user.name=admin
security.user.password=new_password
```

Credit to [this post](https://kielczewski.eu/2015/01/application-metrics-with-spring-boot-actuator/)

Comment: Thanks! Helped me to take the right path. Thanks for the article too.